# Topojson file with US census bureau divisions

Tags: d3.js, geospatial, topojson

My goal is to create a topojson file that contains the US states together with [census bureau divisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_of_the_United_States#Census_Bureau-designated_regions_and_divisions). The idea is then to visualize this with d3.js and use different style for the division borders.

There are few tutorials available for generating the state and county shapes but I'm having trouble getting started with the divisions. Is this data publicly available or do I have to somehow create it myself by merging states?

In addition, I would also need separate files for each division.

Comment: If you downvote, please comment why.

Comment: To work with a base map you need to go first with some GIS tools like: QGIS or ArcGIS. Once your done with the map, export as .GeoJSON and then compact it to .TopoJSON. Now you're able to work with D3. And you right, people downvoting please comment why.-

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the divisions are available in the shapefiles provided by the US census bureau. The divisions and states can be merged into a single topojson file roughly as follows:

```
ogr2ogr divisions.shp tl_2015_us_state.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM tl_2015_us_state GROUP BY DIVISION"

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON divisions.geojson divisions.shp

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON states.geojson tl_2015_us_state.shp

topojson -o us.topojson divisions.geojson states.geojson
```

The ogr2ogr executable comes with the [Geospatial Data Abstraction Library](http://www.gdal.org/) and the shapefile for the states can be downloaded from the [US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) website.

The division specific files can be generated by filtering on the division attribute:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM tl_2015_us_state WHERE DIVISION='9'" pacific.geojson tl_2015_us_state.shp
```